# How to deny folder and file type access - NGINX PHP 8 Azure Web App Service

Tags: php, azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service, nginx-config

I understand that one cannot change nginx.config on the PHP 8 Azure Web App Service as a method to limit access to folders or file types. Similar to .htaccess for Apache.

What is the work around to limit folder and file type access for the NGINX PHP 8 Azure Web App Service?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is to use `chmod < Your Permissions> < Your File Name>` which will be showing as if it has removed write permissions but we mount a location in Azure Storage to the /home mount point when you use the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE  app configuration to persist storage.

Permissions on this are set to 777 by default.Even if you try to modify these permissions through an initialization script or SSH, you probably wouldn't be able to.

REFERENCE:

[Web Apps and Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#you-cannot-change-permissions-on-the-home-directory-when-persisting-storageapplies-to-web-app-for-containers)

[Folder permission for Azure Web App For Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943946/folder-permission-for-azure-web-app-for-linux)

Answer (score 0):

folow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71389502/8425068

to add 'Set your app service startup command' go to Azure > WebApp > Configuration > General > Startup add : /home/site/startup.sh